# Hightlighting keywords in one worksheet from a list found in a second worksheet

Tags: excel, highlight

I have been trying this for a while.  I'm almost there but my vba skills are just short of getting this done.  I have some text in a worksheet that I need to search and find all of the instances of some keywords.

Ideally, I'd have the keywords in a range on a second worksheet.  I can't figure it out.  I have been able to use the following to search for a fixed array but can't figure out how to take it to the next step of getting the words from the worksheet it self.

```
Sub X()

Dim vntWords As Variant
Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String
Dim lngPos As Long

vntWords = Array("sales", "job")

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For lngIndex = LBound(vntWords) To UBound(vntWords)
        Set rngFind = .Find(vntWords(lngIndex), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            strFirstAddress = rngFind.Address
            Do
                lngPos = 0
                Do
                    lngPos = InStr(lngPos + 1, rngFind.Value, vntWords(lngIndex), vbTextCompare)
                    If lngPos > 0 Then
                        With rngFind.Characters(lngPos, Len(vntWords(lngIndex)))
                            .Font.Bold = True
                            .Font.Size = .Font.Size
                            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        End With
                    End If
                Loop While lngPos > 0
                Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
            Loop While rngFind.Address <> strFirstAddress
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

May be that would be helpful for you

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of sheet with search terms").Range("A1:A")
```

This will gave you all values in `A` column as an array. That you can use in your code.

Comment: I replaced the vntWords = Array("sales", "job") with vntWords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Keywords").Range("A1:A") and got a "Run-time error 1004 Appplicaiton-defined or object-defined error" so that didn't seem to work.

Comment: What I was trying to do in that case to get a sheet by name, so try this with latest VBA syntax `Worksheets("Keywords").Range("A1:A")`